# Azure IoT hub example ESP8266 Compiler error

Tags: azure, esp8266

Arduino SDK 1.8.8
Azure libraries: 1.0.45

When I compile (with Arduini IDE 1.8.8) Azure IoT hub example (Command center) for ESP8288 I'll get next error: Same error comes also with all other Azure examples.

C:\Users\naakar\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AzureIoTHub\src/sdk/serializer.h:441:79: error: 'REFLECTED_17' undeclared here (not in a function)

```
 static const REFLECTED_DATA_FROM_DATAPROVIDER ALL_REFLECTED(name) = { &C2(REFLECTED_, C1(DEC(__COUNTER__))) };

                                                                           ^
```

C:\Users\naakar\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AzureIoTUtility\src/azure_c_shared_utility/macro_utils.h:4359:18: note: in definition of macro 'C2_'

#define C2_(x,y) x##y

?? Any Idea what to check ?

Comment: If the proposed solution below doesn't work for you, please also file an issue here https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c with the necessary logs so we can debug further.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

....same problem on 2.5Beta version of the esp8266 board package, can it be so that you are using that one as well, if so try to downgrade to 2.4.2 and it will work!

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f561516f-8cf2-4311-8532-ae8c934c3ba6/esp8266-azure-example-compile-error?forum=azureiothub

Comment: kindly consider adding more details from the link in you answer